# Center pie chart

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, apexcharts

I am using a pie chart from Apex to visualize data. Now I would like to center this pie chart in a vuetify card element, but unfortunately I can't get this to work.
Currently, it looks like this:

```html
<v-card elevation="2" class="ma-3 mx-auto">
    <v-card-title>
        Odds
    </v-card-title>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-card-text>
        <div id="chart3">
          <apexchart type="pie" width="550" :options="chartOptions3" :series="series3"></apexchart>
        </div>
    </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

Visually, it will look like this:

[image]

How can I center the pie chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `d-flex` and `justify-center` utility CSS classes that set `display:flex` and `justify-contents:center`, respectively, on `<v-card-text>`:

```html
<v-card-text class="d-flex justify-center">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/centering-contents-of-v-card-text-mkrdj)